# AWS DynamoDB Golang issue with inserting items into table

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-dynamodb

I've been following Miguel C's [tutorial](https://medium.com/@doncicuto/getting-started-with-dynamodb-in-go-part-1-a25c5522edd4) on setting up a DynamoDB table in golang but modified my json to look like this instead of using movies. I modified the movie struct into a Fruit struct (so there is no more info) and in my schema I defined the partition key as "Name" and the Sort Key as "Price". But when I run my code it says

> "ValidationException: One of the required keys was not given a value"

despite me printing out the input as

> map[name:{
>     S: "bananas"
>   } price:{
>     N: "0.25"
>   }]

which clearly shows that String bananas and Number 0.25 both have values in them.

My Json below looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "bananas",
    "price": 0.25
  },
  {
    "name": "apples",
    "price": 0.50
  }
]
```

Comment: what if you use `Name` instead of `name`?

Comment: That was the issue. I thought I didn't have to worry about capitalization since it's just getting the json into golang as a Fruit struct but put was looking at the "name" and "price" as keys, which ofc didn't exist. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Capitalization issue, changed "name" to "Name" and it worked out.